# Queue.dequeue hanging in Tensorflow input pipeline

Tags: python, input, tensorflow, queue, kaggle

First, thanks for reading this and for the help.

Im trying to built a input pipeline for mnist classification using conv2d in tersorflow. My dataset is the kaggle csv file, and the file have rows:
label, features1, features2, feature3,..., feature 784

Heres the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import tensorflow as tf
from math import ceil
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

test_state = False
submission_state = True
continue_training = True
verbose = False
run_n = 1

if test_state:
    epochs = 1
    submission_state = False
else:
    epochs = 33                     

batch_size = 128                      

save_freq = 1000
summaries_freq = 33

save_dir = "./save/"
save_name = "cnn.ckpt"
summaries_train_dir = './summaries/train/train{0}'.format(run_n)
summaries_eval_dir = './summaries/eval/eval{0}'.format(run_n)
if submission_state:
    save_dir = "./savesubmission/"
    save_name = "cnnsubmit{0}.ckpt".format(run_n)
    summaries_train_dir = './summaries/train/submit{0}'.format(run_n)
submit_file = "MNIST_Kaggle_submission_file{0}.csv".format(run_n)

#DEBUG
display_img = False
n_display = 5
##############################################FUNÇOES AUXILIARES########################################################

def get_data(file): #realiza a aquisiçao dos dados no formato apropriado para serem utilizados no treinamento
    data = pd.read_csv(file) #le o arquivo csv com a biblioteca pandas
    if(verbose == True):
        print('data({0[0]},{0[1]})'.format(data.shape)) #printa o formato dos dados adquiridos (n_samples, n_pixels+n_labels)
    images = data.iloc[:,1:].values #Desfaz o DataFrame que é criado quando importa-se os dados pelo pandas
    images = images.astype(np.float) #Converte dados para float32
    images = np.multiply(images, 1.0 / 255.0)# Normaliza a intensidade de pixel de [0:255]
                                             # para [0.0:1.0], ajuda na aprendizagem
    image_size = images.shape[1]
    image_width = image_height = np.ceil(np.sqrt(image_size)).astype(np.uint8)
    if(verbose == True):
        print('image_width => {0}\nimage_height => {1}'.format(image_width,image_height))
    images = images.reshape([-1, image_width, image_height, 1])
    labels = data[[0]].values.ravel() #adquire os rotulos das imagens em ordem
    n_classes = np.unique(labels).shape[0] #Retorna o numero de rotulos unicos no array (sem contar repetidos)
    n_labels = labels.shape[0]
    index_offset = np.arange(n_labels) * n_classes
    labels_one_hot = np.zeros((n_labels, n_classes))
    labels_one_hot.flat[index_offset + labels.ravel()] = 1
    labels_one_hot = labels_one_hot.astype(np.uint8)
    if(verbose == True):
        print("X shape: {0}, Y shape: {1}".format(images.shape, labels_one_hot.shape))
    return dict(
        Y = labels_one_hot,
        X = images,
        n_samples = int(data.shape[0]),
        n_features = int(images.shape[1]),
        n_classes = int(n_classes)
    )


def split_data(dataset, eval_size=0.2): #divide o set de dados em treinamento e validaçao
    eval_size = int(dataset['n_samples'] * eval_size)
    eval_images = dataset['X'][:eval_size]
    eval_labels = dataset['Y'][:eval_size]
    train_images = dataset['X'][eval_size:]
    train_labels = dataset['Y'][eval_size:]
    if(verbose == True):
        print('train images shape: {0}'.format(train_images.shape))
        print('eval images shape: {0}'.format(eval_images.shape))
    return dict(
        Y = train_labels,
        X = train_images,
        Y_eval = eval_labels,
        X_eval = eval_images,
        n_samples = int(train_images.shape[0]),
        n_eval = int(eval_images.shape[0]),
        n_features = int(train_images.shape[1]),
        n_classes = int(train_labels.shape[1])
    )


def iterator(data, batch_index, batch_size, shuffle):
    if shuffle:
        index = np.random.choice(data['n_samples'], batch_size)
        X_iter = data['X'][index]
        Y_iter = data['Y'][index]
        yield (X_iter, Y_iter)
    else:
        if ((batch_index + 1) > (data['n_samples'] // batch_size)):
            index = np.arange((data['n_samples'] // batch_size) * batch_size,
                              (data['n_samples'] // batch_size) * batch_size  + ceil((data['n_samples'] % batch_size)))
            X_iter = data['X'][index]
            Y_iter = data['Y'][index]
            yield (X_iter, Y_iter)
        else:
            index = np.arange(batch_index * batch_size, (batch_index + 1) * batch_size)
            X_iter = data['X'][index]
            Y_iter = data['Y'][index]
            yield (X_iter, Y_iter)

def get_epoch(data, epochs, batch_size, shuffle):
        n_batches = (data['n_samples'] // batch_size) + 1
        for _ in range(epochs):
            for batch_index in range(n_batches):
                yield iterator(data, batch_index, batch_size, shuffle)


def display(X, label):
    for index in range(n_display):
        image = X[index].reshape(28,28)
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.imshow(image, cmap=cm.binary)
        plt.title(str(np.argmax(label[index])))
        plt.show()


##################################################CNN GRAPH#############################################################

def reset_graph():
    if 'sess' in globals() and sess:
        sess.close()
    tf.reset_default_graph()

def model():

    reset_graph()

    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 1])
    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

    dropout = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

    with tf.name_scope('trainning_time'):
        time = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    with tf.name_scope('mi_params'):
        window = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
        loss = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])

    p_keep_conv = p_keep_hidden = dropout

    with tf.variable_scope('weights') as scope:
        w1a = init_var('w1a', [3, 3, 1, 8])  # 3x3x1 conv, 32 outputs
        B1a = init_var('B1a', [8])
        w1b = init_var('w1b', [3, 3, 8, 16])  # 3x3x1 conv, 32 outputs
        B1b = init_var('B1b', [16])
        w2a = init_var('w2a', [3, 3, 16, 32])  # 3x3x32 conv, 64 outputs
        B2a = init_var('B2a', [32])
        w3a = init_var('w3a', [3, 3, 32, 64])  # 3x3x32 conv, 64 outputs
        B3a = init_var('B3a', [64])
        w4 = init_var('w4', [64 * 4 * 4, 1024])  # FC 64 * 4 * 4 inputs, 128 outputs
        B4 = init_var('B4' ,[1024])
        w_o = init_var('w_o', [1024, 10])  # FC 625 inputs, 10 outputs (labels)
        B_o = init_var('B_o', [10])
        adami = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.999999, dtype=tf.float32), 'adami')

    with tf.variable_scope('cells') as scope:
        l1a = tf.nn.elu(tf.add(tf.nn.conv2d(X, w1a,
                        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'), B1a))
        l1b = tf.nn.elu(tf.add(tf.nn.conv2d(l1a, w1b,
                                      strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'), B1b))

        l1 = tf.nn.max_pool(l1b, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
        l1 = tf.nn.dropout(l1, p_keep_conv)

        l2a = tf.nn.elu(tf.add(tf.nn.conv2d(l1, w2a,
                        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'), B2a))
        l2 = tf.nn.max_pool(l2a, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
        l2 = tf.nn.dropout(l2, p_keep_conv)

        l3a = tf.nn.elu(tf.add(tf.nn.conv2d(l2, w3a,
                        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'), B3a))
        l3 = tf.nn.max_pool(l3a, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
        l3 = tf.nn.dropout(l3, p_keep_conv)

        l3_plain = tf.reshape(l3, [-1, w4.get_shape().as_list()[0]])

        l4 = tf.nn.elu(tf.add(tf.matmul(l3_plain, w4), B4))
        l4 = tf.nn.dropout(l4, p_keep_hidden)

        logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(l4, w_o), B_o)   #printa o formato da matriz de rotulos para conferencia

        prediction = tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(logits), 1)

    with tf.name_scope('total_loss'):
        total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, Y))

    with tf.name_scope('learning_rate'):
        learning_rate = tf.add(tf.nn.relu(tf.multiply(7e-4, adami)), 1e-12)

        def adami_down(adami, learning_rate):
            new = tf.add(tf.nn.relu(tf.sub(adami, tf.multiply(adami, learning_rate))), 1e-6)
            with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assign(adami, new)]):
                return tf.identity(adami)

        adami = tf.cond(tf.reduce_mean(loss[-window:]) >= tf.reduce_mean(loss[-(2 * window):-(window)]),
                        lambda: adami_down(adami, learning_rate), lambda: tf.identity(adami))

    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(total_loss)
    tf.add_to_collection('train_step', train_step)

    with tf.name_scope('correct_prediction'):
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
    with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
        tf.add_to_collection('accuracy', accuracy)

    tf.summary.histogram('w1a', w1a)
    tf.summary.histogram('B1a', B1a)
    tf.summary.histogram('w1b', w1b)
    tf.summary.histogram('B1b', B1b)
    tf.summary.histogram('w2a', w2a)
    tf.summary.histogram('B2a', B2a)
    tf.summary.histogram('w3a', w3a)
    tf.summary.histogram('B3a', B3a)
    tf.summary.histogram('w_o', w_o)
    tf.summary.histogram('B_o', B_o)
    tf.summary.histogram('l1a', l1a)
    tf.summary.histogram('l1b', l1b)
    tf.summary.histogram('l1_pool', l1)
    tf.summary.histogram('l2a', l2a)
    tf.summary.histogram('l2_pool', l2)
    tf.summary.histogram('l3a', l3a)
    tf.summary.histogram('l3_pool', l3)
    tf.summary.histogram('l4_fully', l4)
    elapsed_time = tf.summary.scalar('trainning_time', time)
    tf.summary.scalar('total_loss', total_loss)
    tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy)
    tf.summary.scalar('learning_rate', learning_rate)
    tf.summary.scalar('adami', adami)
    tf.summary.scalar('dropout_keep_probability', dropout)

    summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

    return dict(
        x = X,
        y = Y,
        learning_rate = learning_rate,
        pred = prediction,
        train_step = train_step,
        total_loss = total_loss,
        accuracy = accuracy,
        adami = adami,
        window = window,
        loss = loss,
        dropout = dropout,
        time = time,
        elapsed_time = elapsed_time,
        summaries = summary_op,
        saver=tf.train.Saver()
    )

def init_var(name, shape):
    return tf.get_variable(name, shape, initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

################################################# TRAINING #############################################################

def train_network(data, g, epochs, batch_size, save, verbose=True):
    with tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph()) as sess:
        train_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(summaries_train_dir,
                                              sess.graph)
        if(continue_training == False):
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            print("Model created.")
            if isinstance(save, str):
                g['saver'].save(sess, save)
                print('Model Saved.')
        else:
            new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('{0}.meta'.format(tf.train.latest_checkpoint('{0}'.format(save_dir))))
            new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('{0}'.format(save_dir)))
            print("Model Restored.")
            print("Resuming Training.")
        sess.graph.finalize()
        training_losses = []
        accu = []
        window = int(42)
        for k in range(2 * window):
            training_losses.append(2.5)
        for idx, epoch in enumerate(get_epoch(data, epochs, batch_size, shuffle=True)):
            t = time.time()
            training_loss = 0
            accuracy = 0
            steps = 0
            for X, Y in epoch:
                feed_dict={g['x']: X,
                           g['y']: Y,
                           g['window']: window,
                           g['loss']: training_losses,
                           g['dropout']: 0.72,
                           g['time']: time.time() - t,
                            }

                training_loss_ , _, accuracy_, adami, learning_rate = sess.run([g['total_loss'],
                                                                                g['train_step'],
                                                                                g['accuracy'],
                                                                                g['adami'],
                                                                                g['learning_rate']],
                                                                                feed_dict)

                training_loss += training_loss_
                accuracy += accuracy_

                elapsed_time = sess.run(g['elapsed_time'], feed_dict={g['time']: time.time() - t})
                train_writer.add_summary(elapsed_time, global_step=int((idx * batch_size) + steps))

                if(idx%summaries_freq == 0):
                    summary = sess.run(g['summaries'], feed_dict)
                    train_writer.add_summary(summary, global_step=int((idx * batch_size) + steps))

                steps += 1

            training_losses.append(training_loss/steps)
            accu.append(accuracy/steps)

            if(idx%save_freq == 0 and idx != 0):
                if isinstance(save, str):
                    g['saver'].save(sess, save, global_step=idx)
                    print('Model Saved.')

            n_iterations = ((epochs * data['n_samples']) // batch_size)

            if verbose:
                print("Training loss for iteration {0}/{1}: {2}, Learning Rate:{6}, AdaMi: {8},"
                                                " Accuracy: {7} %, ETC: {3}:{4}:{5}".format(idx,
                                                        n_iterations,
                                                        training_loss / steps,
                                                        int(((time.time() - t) * (n_iterations - idx + 1)) // 3600),
                                                        int((((time.time() - t) * (n_iterations - idx + 1)) % 3600) // 60),
                                                        int((((time.time() - t) * (n_iterations - idx + 1)) % 3600) % 60),
                                                        learning_rate,
                                                        (accuracy / steps) * 100,
                                                        adami))
                print("It took {0} seconds to train this epoch.".format(time.time() - t))

        g['saver'].save(sess, save)
        print('Model Saved.')
    return [training_losses, accu]

# output image
if(display_img == True):
    for i in range(n_display):
        display(data['X'], data['Y'])

g = model()
t = time.time()

mnist = get_data(file='train.csv')  # chama a funçao get_data

if (verbose == True):
    # printa o formato da matriz de rotulos para conferencia
    print('labels shape: ({0} samples, {1} classes)'.format(mnist['n_samples'], mnist['n_classes']))
    # printa o formato da matriz de imagens para conferencia
    print(
        'images shape: ({0} samples, {1[1]} x {1[2]} x {1[3]} pixels)'.format(mnist['n_samples'], mnist['X'].shape))

# chama a funçao split_data, dividindo o set de dados em treinamento e eval
if not submission_state:
    data = split_data(mnist)
if submission_state:
    data = mnist

print("Starting Trainning")

        #  dos dados e no tamanho do batch
losses , accuracy = train_network(data, g, epochs ,batch_size, save="{0}{1}".format(save_dir,save_name))

print("It took {0} seconds to train for {1} epochs.".format(time.time()-t, epochs))
print("The average loss on the final epoch was:", np.mean(losses[-1]))

##################################################### EVAL #############################################################

def eval_network(data, g, batch_size, verbose):
    with tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph()) as sess:
        eval_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(summaries_eval_dir)
        new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('{0}.meta'.format(tf.train.latest_checkpoint('{0}'.format(save_dir))))
        new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('{0}'.format(save_dir)))
        print("Model Restored.")
        sess.graph.finalize()
        eval_losses = []
        accu = []
        window = int(7)
        for k in range(2 * window):
            eval_losses.append(0)
        for idx, epoch in enumerate(get_epoch(data, 1, batch_size, shuffle=False)):
            eval_loss = 0
            steps = 0
            accuracy = 0
            t = time.time()
            for X, Y in epoch:
                feed_dict={g['x']: X,
                           g['y']: Y,
                           g['window']: window,
                           g['loss']: eval_losses,
                           g['dropout']: 1.0,
                           g['time']: time.time() - t,
                           }

                eval_loss_ , pred , accuracy_ = sess.run([g['total_loss'],
                                                          g['pred'],
                                                          g['accuracy']],
                                                          feed_dict)

                if(idx % summaries_freq == 0):
                    summary = sess.run(g['summaries'], feed_dict)
                    eval_writer.add_summary(summary, global_step=int((idx * batch_size) + steps))

                eval_loss += eval_loss_
                accuracy += accuracy_

                steps += 1

            if verbose:
                print("Average eval loss: {0}, Accuracy: {1} % ".format(eval_loss/steps, (accuracy/steps) * 100))
                print("It took", time.time() - t, "seconds to eval this epoch.")
            eval_losses.append(eval_loss/steps)
            accu.append(accuracy/steps)

    return [eval_losses, accu]

t = time.time()
g = model()

if not submission_state:
    data = dict(X = data['X_eval'], Y = data['Y_eval'], n_samples = data['n_eval'])
        #  dos dados e no tamanho do batch
    print("Evaluating NN")

    losses, accuracy = eval_network(data, g, batch_size, verbose)

    print("It took {0} seconds to eval".format(time.time() - t,))
    print("The average loss was: {0}, and the accuracy was: {1} %".format(np.mean(losses), np.mean(accuracy) * 100))

########################################## PREDICT AND SAVE FOR SUBMISSION #############################################

def get_pred_data(file): #realiza a aquisiçao dos dados no formato apropriado para serem utilizados no treinamento
    data = pd.read_csv(file) #le o arquivo csv com a biblioteca pandas
    if(verbose == True):
        print('data({0[0]},{0[1]})'.format(data.shape)) #printa o formato dos dados adquiridos (n_samples, n_pixels+n_labels)
    images = data.values #Desfaz o DataFrame que é criado quando importa-se os dados pelo pandas
    images = images.astype(np.float) #Converte dados para float32
    images = np.multiply(images, 1.0 / 255.0)# Normaliza a intensidade de pixel de [0:255]
                                             # para [0.0:1.0], ajuda na aprendizagem
    image_size = images.shape[1]
    image_width = image_height = np.ceil(np.sqrt(image_size)).astype(np.uint8)
    if(verbose == True):
        print('image_width => {0}\nimage_height => {1}'.format(image_width,image_height))
    images = images.reshape([-1, image_width, image_height, 1])
    labels = np.zeros((int(data.shape[0]), 10))
    if(verbose == True):
        print("X shape: {0}".format(images.shape))
    return dict(
        X = images,
        Y = labels,
        n_samples = int(data.shape[0]),
        n_features = int(images.shape[1]),
    )


def predict_logits(data, g, batch_size, verbose):
    with tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph()) as sess:
        new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('{0}.meta'.format(tf.train.latest_checkpoint('{0}'.format(save_dir))))
        new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('{0}'.format(save_dir)))
        print("Model Restored.")
        sess.graph.finalize()
        predictions = []
        index = []
        for idx, epoch in enumerate(get_epoch(data, 1, batch_size, shuffle=False)):
            steps = 0
            t = time.time()
            for X, Y in epoch:
                feed_dict={g['x']: X,
                           g['dropout']: 1.0,
                           }

                pred = sess.run(g['pred'], feed_dict)

                predictions.extend(pred.ravel())

                steps += 1

            if verbose:
                print("It took", time.time() - t, "seconds to make the predictions.")

    answer = []
    for idx, value in enumerate(predictions):
        index.append(idx + 1)
        answer.append(value)
    predictions = pd.DataFrame(answer, index=index)
    print("Predictions:\n Index, Label\n", predictions)
    return predictions

if submission_state or test_state:
    mnist = get_pred_data(file='test.csv') #chama a funçao get_data

    if(verbose == True):
        #printa o formato da matriz de rotulos para conferencia
        print('labels shape: ({0} samples)'.format(mnist['n_samples']))
        #printa o formato da matriz de imagens para conferencia
        print('images shape: ({0} samples, {1[1]} x {1[2]} x {1[3]} pixels)'.format(mnist['n_samples'], mnist['X'].shape))

    t = time.time()
    g = model()

    print("Making Predictions")

    predictions = predict_logits(mnist, g, batch_size, verbose)
    print("It took {0} seconds to predict logits".format(time.time() - t,))

    print("Saving predictions to csv file.")
    predictions.to_csv(submit_file, index_label=['ImageId'], header=['Label'])
    print("File saved.")

reset_graph()
```

What happens is thats  it hangs after:

```
training_loss_ , _, accuracy_, adami, learning_rate = sess.run([g['total_loss'],
                                                                                g['train_step'],
                                                                                g['accuracy'],
                                                                                g['adami'],
                                                                                g['learning_rate']],
                                                                                feed_dict)
```

I can see in the tensorboard that my queues are not being filled, but i cant find why.

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

The standard MNIST images have 28 x 28 = 784 pixels. Assuming that each column in the CSV file is a different pixel, plus one column for the label, the following line in your code:

```
for column in range(749):
```

…should be:

```
for column in range(785):
```

Comment: yea.... that must be the worse question of all times....
thanks for the advise.
I got it right, but now i get the following error:

TypeError: 'FIFOQueue' object is not iterable

What m i getting wrong?

Comment: I think you want `X, Y = tf.train.batch([features, labels], …)` rather than creating a `tf.train.slice_input_producer()`.

Comment: I tried what you said but got:

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_1_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 128, current size 0)
  [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@batch/fifo_queue"], component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch/fifo_queue, batch/n)]]

Comment: That sounds like you have another problem somewhere earlier in the graph construction. Look earlier in the logs to see if other things failed, and feel free to ask another question… it's hard to read a lot of logs in the comments :).